# Cannot assign value using a custom subscript method with a setter

Tags: swift

This is from apple's official documentation(slightly modified) -

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}


class Residence {
    var rooms = [Room]()
    var numberOfRooms: Int {
        return rooms.count
    }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Room {
        get {
            return rooms[i]
        }
        set {
            rooms[i] = newValue
        }
    }
}

class Room {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}

let john = Person()
let johnsHouse = Residence()

johnsHouse.rooms.append(Room(name: "Living Room")) 
johnsHouse.rooms.append(Room(name: "Kitchen"))
john.residence = johnsHouse 

let firstRoomName = john.residence?[0].name
print(firstRoomName)
```

prints - Optional("Living Room")

So, above program uses getter (even if I omit setter, prints the same). This time I want to use setter instead of getter. How to go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a value to a specific element of `Residence.rooms` just like you would do for a normal `Array`. The subscript method of `Residence` simply makes it possible to leave out `.rooms` when accessing a specific element of `Residence.rooms`, so you can simply do `Residence[n]` to access `Residence.rooms[n]`.

So if you want to assign a value to a `Room` by calling the setter of `Residence.subscript`, you simply need to do

```
john.residence?[0] = Room(name: "Bedroom")
```

The setter of `subscript` only gets called when you assign a value to the value returned by the subscript like in the code above.

Be aware that the subscript method of `Residence` doesn't guard against out of range access, so you cannot add new elements to the `rooms` array using the subscript setter method. So for instance following your example code if you tried to add a 3rd room instead of modifying one of the two existing rooms by doing `john.residence?[2] = Room(name: "Bedroom")`, you'd receive a runtime *"Index out of range."* error.

Comment: ok, I want to print(firstRoom) =        BedRoom or  Optional("BedRoom")..How

Comment: @askit just do `print(john.residence?[0])` after `john.residence?[0] = Room(name: "Bedroom")`

Comment: I did what you told. I added it in the end. It prints -  Optional(main.Room)

Comment: @askit my bad, you should print `john.residence?[0].name`